# Watson Assistant issue : On giving condition to jump from one node to another node Intents as suggestions are getting picked instead of entities

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Lets say I have 2 nodes : Node A and Node B.
The condition (entity created) of Node A is @abc.
The condition (entity created) of Node B is @def.
I have to jump from Node A to Node B.

Dialog try out Panel:
Greeting message
@abc condition given (Watson jumped to Node A)
@def condition given (Watson SHOULD jump to Node B but instead of picking @def condition, Suggestions[Intents] are getting picked which results in wrong jumping.)

Could anyone help me on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the nodes on the same level or parent / child? Anything else set?

Comment: The nodes are the child nodes but all are at same level.

Comment: Add more details. It is not clear what problem you are facing.

Comment: I am giving the exact same condition of node b but not sure why suggestions(intents) are getting picked. I even tried changing the condition name of that node but still intents are getting picked.

Comment: From the description in the question above (not any comments), anybody who wants to help should be able to understand what you are doing and to bring in their experience to provide advise. Right now, the question is lacking that.

Comment: Maybe you can do a screen grab of your nodes, thus showing your layout. Which may be easier to debug. I believe the issue you are having is that the conditions for the second node are not being selected.